# How to detect all the visible sprites in a layer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, visibility, sprite

Can I detect all the visible sprites in a layer in order to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i assume u r using Box2d with cocos2d

```
//here create ccsprite and add them to ur scene

while create body with bodydef

    bodydef.userData=ccspriteobject;

    for (b2Body* b = m_world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
    {
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        //if the userdata is not null then ur sprite

            CCSprite *actor = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
```

Comment: Your solution is only viable if he uses box2d.

Comment: @ Aaron Goselin : it is the correct answer because I am using Box2d

Comment: Yeah but you didn't state that, nor did you even tag it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small function you can use:

```
-(void)getAllChildren {
    CCArray *childrenArray = [self children];
    for(CCNode *myNode in childrenArray)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That will only loop through all children of a CCNode. You should then perform a `if( [myNode visible] ) {}` check as well, to have this detect visible sprites.

Comment: @nash. That's true. But I left that out since sprites can be invisible in different ways. They can have alpha set 0 or they can be outside the screen. Just figured that the code was sufficient Bobj-C.